# If / Else statement in a loop, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Hi For some reason the console is returning to me SyntaxError: Unexpected token else, but I don't really know the problem, can someone help me please ?

```
lineN = ["Times Square", "34th", "28th", "23rd", "Union Square", "8th"];
storeStops = [];

 function input ( start, stop ){

    if (lineN.indexOf(start)<lineN.indexOf(stop)){
        for (var fwd =lineN.indexOf(start) ; fwd < lineN.indexOf(stop) ;foward++);
        fwd.push(storeStops);
    }}
    else {for (var bwd =lineN.indexOf(start) ; bwd < lineN.indexOf(stop) ;bwd--);
        bwd.push(storeStops)
    };
```

Comment: 3 lines below the 'if' condition, there is a double mustache, remove one to the end to close the function keyword

Comment: Paste your code into http://jsbeautifier.org/ and let it indent it properly and your errors will be very obvious.

Comment: In addition to @wonyeouuu's comment, you have `;` after `for` which will stop loop. And more importantly, `fwd =lineN.indexOf(start)` and then `fwd.push(storeStops)`. You cannot push to a variable. `push` is a function of array. Also, you do not increment `fwd`, which will make it never ending loop.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var lineN = ["Times Square", "34th", "28th", "23rd", "Union Square", "8th"];
var storeStops = [];

function input (start, stop) {
  if (lineN.indexOf(start) < lineN.indexOf(stop)) {
    for (var fwd =lineN.indexOf(start) ; fwd < lineN.indexOf(stop) ;foward++);
    fwd.push(storeStops);
  } else {
    for (var bwd =lineN.indexOf(start) ; bwd < lineN.indexOf(stop) ;bwd--);
    bwd.push(storeStops);
  }
}
```

You should indent your code correctly so that these things are easier to catch. You were missing a couple of braces and brackets here and there. Also, in JavaScript there is no `;` after `if/else` blocks.

Comment: Even this will not work. Please execute your code once before posting it. You have `;` after `for` and `fwd | bwd` are variables and not `arrays`. it should be reverse `storeStops.push(...)`. Also I downvoted your answer. Some how it turned into upvote. Strange! Some SO bug.

Comment: This will work. You do not know what the logic of OP is. Author seems to be incrementing `foward` a few times, that is why I kept the `;` after the for loop. It might be what he wanted.

Comment: If thats so, you can suggest OP to use `stopIndex-startIndex` instead of looping. Also `fwd.push` will never work. No matter what. And you should confirm if thats what OP wants. In my understanding, ge wants index range between 2 words.

Comment: yes, sorry about that, I'm very beginer learner.. I know there is a lot of mistakes... like Rajesh said is that exacly what I want index range betwen 2 words.. and then put inside the other array to log

Comment: @LucasVilela its al right. You can rectify typos in your question and also explain what you are trying to achieve. This way people will be able help you

Comment: @LucasVilela I have created a sample for you. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/r5Lse06d/2/). Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks soo much Rajesh!! This is a great help!! I'm very glad to find helpful people like you here ! Thank you